# What algorithm does babel use to convert a simple div into x.createElement('div')?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am curious how babel's algorithm works for converting JSX into

```
x.createElement(
  type,
  [props],
  [...children]
)
```

Can anyone explain how babel works for a simple JSX div?

```
<div id="hello-world" > Hello World </div>
```

Comment: If you want to know how open source code works, you can just look at the code and discover it yourself.

Comment: It's not exactly easy to figure out the basics of how something like babel works, which is why I am asking here to see if anyone has already done the work of looking at the source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Babel is a compiler. It's not that simple.

Most compilers break down into three primary stages: Parsing, Transformation, and Code Generation

1. *Parsing* is taking raw code and turning it into a more abstract representation of the code. (Parsing working example: [here](https://astexplorer.net/). Go ahead, use your `<div>` example.)
2. *Transformation* takes this abstract representation and manipulates to do whatever the compiler wants it to.
3. *Code Generation* takes the transformed representation of the code and turns it into new code.

For a quick tutorial on compilers, see [this](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/the-super-tiny-compiler/blob/master/the-super-tiny-compiler.js).

Another great resource on Babel internal working. [here](https://itnext.io/parse-react-components-with-babel-and-visualize-them-45062046cb72).

Comment: Thank you so much!